# An antonym or counterpoint of transcendent?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to compare the concepts of "Virtue and Meaning" to "Resilience and Wellbeing" in people and organisations.

My current thinking is to call "Virtue and Meaning" *transcendent*, but I can't find an antonym or counterpoint term to express "Resilience and Wellbeing".

My conception is that meaning and virtue are more abstract concepts, whereas resilience and wellbeing are more grounded in objective reality, ie: more measurable, observable, physical, tangible. Is there a word that might describe this?

Similarly, is there a better word than "transcendent" for virtue & meaning?

Comment: Apologies if I've breached site rules. I'm not married to the word transcendent for virtue and meaning--if there is a better term to distinguish them from resilience and wellbeing that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand how (non-)transcendence has anything to do with virtue, meaning, resilience or wellbeing..!

Comment: @Rachel: Maybe you should divorce trancendence in the question, to make it clearer to people that you're open to other terms.

Comment: mundane? pedestrian? what did a thesaurus suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The first term that comes to mind is "material", in the adjective sense which means "pertaining to physical reality".

In a religious or spiritual context, a better term might be "worldly" (meaning "of the physical world"), "fleshly" (meaning "of one's physical body"), or "temporal" (meaning transient or ephemeral, in contrast to "eternal"). However, in many contexts, all three of these terms may have an association specifically with Christianity, because Christian writings have often used these terms to contrast with the divine or spiritual.